# How to create an activity transition programmatically ?

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to create an animation programmatically to start an activity with zoom effect from touch screen point.

With the next I simulate a zoom enter effect:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator" >

<scale
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
    android:fromXScale="0.0"
    android:fromYScale="0.0"
    android:pivotX="50%p"
    android:pivotY="50%p"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0" />
</set>
```

Right now I using the above animation starting from the center of screen (no from touch screen, which I think is better for user experience in this case).

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.zoom_enter, android.R.anim.fade_out);
```

I would like to know if it is possible to create an animation as:

```
AnimationSet animSet = new AnimationSet(false);
ScaleAnimation zoom = new ScaleAnimation(0, 0, 1, 1, 50, 50);
animSet.addAnimation(zoom);
```

(I'll replace the 50, 50 values to the appropriates (touch screen point))
and SET the animation to overridePendingTransition(int, int)

All info I've seen use xml transitions.

Comment: I don't think it's possible.

Answer (score 4):

I did it this way:

I'm created ScaleAnimation in the activity's `OnCreate` method, set it's duration and started it for root view.

```
Animation anim = new ScaleAnimation(0, 1, 0, 1, mTouchX, mTouchY);
anim.setDuration(mAnimDuration); // duration = 300
getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content).startAnimation(anim);
```

It should be after `setContentView` method