# OverridePendingTransition is not working

Tags: android, animation, material-design

I've seen other threads with this issue, but none of them has worked for me.

I have an Activity A, which calls Activity B. I'm doing a fade animation programmatically both entry and exit, and a shared FAB is translated to its new position. This translation works, but the fade does not.

Code of Activity A

```
profilePic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        // Activity A starting Activity B
        Activity activity = MainScreenUI.this;

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainScreenUI.this, ProfileUI.class);

        int[] imageScreenLocation = new int[2];
        profilePic.getLocationInWindow(imageScreenLocation);

        intent.putExtra(Properties.PACKAGE + ".left", imageScreenLocation[0])
              .putExtra(Properties.PACKAGE + ".top", imageScreenLocation[1])
              .putExtra(Properties.PACKAGE + ".width", profilePic.getWidth())
              .putExtra(Properties.PACKAGE + ".height", profilePic.getHeight());

        startActivity(intent);

        activity.overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    }
});
```

Code of Activity B

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

    ...

    mTopLevelLayout = (CoordinatorLayout)findViewById(R.id.profile_coordinator);

    mBackground = new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE);
    mTopLevelLayout.setBackground(mBackground);

    if (savedInstanceState == null)
    {
        final ViewTreeObserver observer = mProfileFAB.getViewTreeObserver();
        observer.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreDraw()
            {
                mProfileFAB.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);

                ...

                _runEnterAnimation();

                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}

private void _runEnterAnimation()
{
    mProfileFAB.setPivotX(0);
    mProfileFAB.setPivotY(0);
    mProfileFAB.setScaleX(mWidthScaleImage);
    mProfileFAB.setScaleY(mHeightScaleImage);
    mProfileFAB.setTranslationX(mLeftDeltaImage);
    mProfileFAB.setTranslationY(mTopDeltaImage);

    mProfileFAB.animate()
               .setDuration(ANIM_DURATION)
               .scaleX(1).scaleY(1)
               .translationX(0).translationY(0)
               .setInterpolator(ACCELERATE_DECELERATE_INTERPOLATOR);

    // This animation is not applied
    ObjectAnimator bgAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(mBackground, "alpha", 0, 255);
    bgAnim.setDuration(ANIM_DURATION);
    bgAnim.start();
}




@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    _runExitAnimation(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            finish();
        }
    });    
}

@Override
public void finish()
{
    super.finish();

    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
}

private void _runExitAnimation(final Runnable endAction)
{
    int[] currentLocation = new int[2];
    mProfileFAB.getLocationOnScreen(currentLocation);
    mTopDeltaImage = mThumbnailTop - currentLocation[1];

    mProfileFAB.animate()
               .setDuration(ANIM_DURATION)
               .setStartDelay(0)
               .scaleX(mWidthScaleImage).scaleY(mHeightScaleImage)
               .translationX(mLeftDeltaImage).translationY(mTopDeltaImage)
               .withEndAction(endAction);

    // This animation is not working either
    ObjectAnimator bgAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(mBackground, "alpha", 0);
    bgAnim.setDuration(ANIM_DURATION);
    bgAnim.start();
}
```

XML of Activity B

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/profile_coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activities.ProfileUI"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/profile_appbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="192dp"
        android:background="@drawable/filter_bottom_border">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/profile_collapsing_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">

            ...

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        ...

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <com.wallakoala.wallakoala.Views.FloatingActionImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_floating_pic"
        android:layout_width="84dp"
        android:layout_height="84dp"
        android:src="@drawable/female_icon"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/profile_appbar_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The strange thing is that this logic is applied in other places and it's working fine, I don't know what I've messed here.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You should rather use `overridePendingTransition()` in the `onCreate()` method of the `Activity` that you are trying to open than after raising the intent for the same.

If you kept the parameters 0 just to hide your code in the question its fine, but if not, let me tell you that it expects animation resource files as the input parameters. You can probably use the fade animations available in the support library as:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.abc_fade_in, R.anim.abc_fade_out);
```

It takes in the first parameter as the enter animation of the `Activity` being opened, the second parameter for the exit animation of the previous one.

Comment: But I'm not using XML animations, I'm doing it prommatically, therefore the overridePendingTransition(0,0)

Comment: I forgot, I tried to use overridePendingTransition() in the onCreate, OnPause, and nothing, same result.

Comment: If you are not using an animation from the resource it won't work, and if you don't want to use animations from resource, `overridePendingTransition` won't serve your purpose.

Comment: Well, It's working in other activity. I tried to find the tutorial where I got this from, but could not find it.

Answer (score 0):

Provide exit and enter animations inside overridePendingTransition() method in your activity A> onclick method. There you provided overridePendingTransition(0,0).

Comment: I'm not using XML animations, I'm doing it prommatically, therefore the overridePendingTransition(0,0)

Comment: Refer this link for ActivitySwitcher option. That might help you. http://blog.robert-heim.de/karriere/android-startactivity-rotate-3d-animation-activityswitcher/comment-page-1/#comment-12025

Comment: Did you see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22325975/how-to-create-an-activity-transition-programmatically. Didnt checked.

Comment: Will give it a try,